# Why does SimpleDateFormat() return wrong month?

Tags: java

The following code gives the wrong information:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GregorianCalendar fmt = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 7, 3);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String result = df.format(fmt.getTime());

        System.out.println("fmt: " + result);

    }
}
```

It outputs:

> fmt: 03-Aug-2000

While I need the Month to be July, as I have set the month to 7?

Comment: And where's the problem, in month or year?

Comment: And what should be the right outcome? Note that months are numbered from 0..

Comment: What do you want obtain??

Comment: Did you want 03-Aug-1975, 03-Jul-1975, or 03-Jul-0075?

Comment: it should return 03-Jul-1975 as i'm setting GregorianCalendar fmt = new GregorianCalendar(75, 7, 3);

Comment: @APar , no you're setting 75, not 1975

Comment: try `new GregorianCalendar(1975, 6, 3);` then. Years start with 0, and so do months. For some random reason (**read the documentation**) days start at 1 though.

Comment: The Gregorian calendar constructor doesn't do what you think it does. It's *not* the same as the `Date` constructor.

Comment: In general, as a software developer you should consider the rule-of-thumb that when a well-established API isn't acting as you expect, it's probably not a problem with the API.

Comment: Why is that Question Down voted that Much?? he just need a suggestion ,

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan if you happen to do a simple search on your favorite SEO (e.g. google) about this you will get lot of links containing the explanation and giving you the tools to solve this. So you can do it by yourself or post a question here without doing any research on the topic and waiting for free help instead.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for explaining the reason, I will keep that point in mind too while posting my Question , Thanks

Comment: thank you all for your help/suggestions/solutions. Sorry for the basic question, i'm new to the java world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted by other people, there are two problems in your current code:

- Months are zero based. So, month 7 is August, not July =\
- Year doesn't start by default at 1900 but at 1970, but if you set the year by yourself you'll get as year the same number you're setting, in this case, 75 (not 1975 as expected).

To solve this, you may create the `GregorianCaledar` as `new GregorianCaledar(1975, 6, 3)`. Or even better, stop working directly with this class and instead use the abstract class [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1975);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 3);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String result = df.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println("fmt: " + result);
```

Why to use `Calendar` instead of `GregorianCalendar`? Because [you should always work with abstract class/interface instead of class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197).

Answer (score 8):

My guess, is that you're expecting the 7th month to be `July`, but the `month` value is 0-based, so July would be represented by a `6`.

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field in the calendar. **Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.**

You also probably want to enter the 4-digit date

You'd end up with the following

```
GregorianCalendar fmt = new GregorianCalendar(1975, 6, 3);
```

Here's the documentation for [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 3):

Of course,

You have instantiated the GregorianCalendar to year 75.

What was your purpose?

See the API

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Also pay attention that in GregorianCalendar the month start from 0

Taken from the JavaDoc above:

"month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field in the calendar. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January."

Answer (score 3):

In the `GregorianCalendar` months are marked from `0` (which represents January), and so do the years. So if you want to represent July 3rd, 1975, you should use:

```
GregorianCalendar fmt = new GregorianCalendar(1975, 6, 3);
```

Comment: *and so do the years* this is the first time I read years are 0 based :|

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza as opposed to the questionably-intuitive 1900-based (consider what you would automatically think a date like 16/11/81 represents).

Comment: Consider what 01/01/01 means: 1st January 1901 or 1st January 2001? :)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2000 , 7 , 3 )
```

…or…

```
LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.JULY , 3 )
```

## java.time

As already noted, the troublesome old `GregorianCalendar` has crazy numbering schemes with year, month, and day-of-week. Months are numbered 0-11 for January-December, so August is # 7 rather than # 8. Avoid these old legacy classes like the Plague. Instead, use the modern *java.time* classes.

Te *java.time* classes use sane numbering:

- `2014` means the year 2014. No funky math with 1900.
- `2` means February, 1-12 for January-December.
- `1` means Monday, 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per [ISO 8601][1] standard.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2000 , 7 , 3 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (2014 means year 2014). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.JULY , 3 ) ;
```

Generate a String in your desired format. Note the `Locale` argument used to specify the human language and cultural norms to be used in localizing.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

> 03-Jul-2000

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).